# How to disable and re-enable an (wireless) network device?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, device-manager

I know I can enable and disable my network Devices in **Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections**. I use the context menu and click on "Disable" and then "Enable".

[image]

Because I have to do this regulary - I don't know why - I want to do this using the shell and create a Batch-program or with powershell or something.

**Is there any way to restart using the command line this particular device?**